# Endless Adapter with custom listview adapter in android

Tags: android

I am using [this link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) to create custom listview in my app.

First I want to display listview with 5 items. As I scroll the list it should parse data and load listview for next 5 items.

Listview row contains 5 textviews.

How can I achieve this?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you read the instructions on the page that you linked to? Did you examine the sample app in the `demo/` subdirectory? If the answer to those two questions are "yes" and "yes", respectively, consider editing your question to ask more specific questions than "how can I achieve this?".

Comment: Yes I tried that demo in device. It is displaying only one item in listview row. I want to display 5 items in single row

Comment: so read the demo code and watch where the list view is populated. You have to populate it with 5 rows not 1. Is there some piece of code that you tried and don't understand?

Comment: yes. I think so. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display 5 items in single row

That has nothing to do with `EndlessAdapter`. That has everything to do with the `ListAdapter` you are putting into the `EndlessAdapter`. Start by *not* using `EndlessAdapter` and getting your list looking the way you want. Then, and only then, add in `EndlessAdapter` to add more data to the list as the user scrolls.

There are countless examples online of how to create rows in a custom `ListAdapter` that have more than one thing in them. [Here is a free excerpt from my book](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) on how to subclass `ArrayAdapter`, override `getView()`, and handle more than one widget in a row. You specifically will want to look at the "Customizing the Adapter" section.

Comment: Yes I know about custom adapter. I've used that with my listview so many times. But how can I integrate that with EndlessAdapter?

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar: The same way you integrate any `ListAdapter` with `EndlessAdapter`, as is described in the project's home page and is demonstrated in the sample app. *You* are the one who thinks something is different.

Comment: Hey can you please arrange some code for me?? It will be very helpful for me

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar: I already did. It is the `demo/` project of the repository. You already looked at it. At this point, perhaps you simply should not be using `EndlessAdapter`. I seem to recall there are other solutions for this UI pattern out there.